# Using Javascript Regex to get part of Href During Mouseover

Tags: javascript, regex, href

I has this Html Code below

```
<div class="first-div">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2014/04/18/post-format-audio-2/#php">PHP</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2014/04/18/post-format-audio-2/#css">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/2014/04/18/post-format-audio-2/#html">HTML</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="second-div"></div>
```

i want when mouseover on PHP,CSS and HTML Link:

1. Create The Javascript REGEX to get only (php,css,html) without # sign from href in first-div.
2. then add (php,css,html) as ID to second-div.

Comment: jQuery doesn't have any regular expression functions. They're just part of native Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex, the part after the `#` is a hash, and is available directly.

```
$('a').on('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('.second-div').prop('id', this.hash.substr(1));
});
```

Not sure why you would ever set the ID dynamically, but whatever floats your goat !

[image]

Comment: boats float, not goats.

Comment: thank you not want on click i want mouseover or hover

Comment: So change `click` to `mouseover`.

Comment: @Barmar - edited my answer to prove it works, the goat thing that is !

Comment: Also -> https://www.google.no/search?q=whatever+floats+your+goat&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=PYFeVKeWKpLjar_fgZgF&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=1075

Comment: i wrote question before one hour about bootstrap tabs in this link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819918/how-show-posts-according-to-categories-by-using-bootstrap-tabs-in-wordpress i want when moseover the tabs directly show the posts rlated to the tabs category. please help me to solve my problem by jquery or php